# Can we use "shore" referring to river?

Tags: word-usage

I saw the usage of "shore" with "river" in a modern American book, however my dictionary says that we should use "bank" with "river". Are there any difference between using "shore" and "bank" or maybe it's Americanism?

Comment: a "bank" is assumed to have a noticeable slant. I think that for a river to have a "shore", the area next to the river would have to be at least a few feet wide, and nearly level; ideally sandy like an ocean beach. Otherwise, it's just a bank.  But you could say you were at the "river's edge" in either case.

Comment: "Bank" would be the "normal" word to use, but how dreary English would be if one only ever used the "normal" word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though  it is a term than can be used referring to a river, especially a wide one,  bank is the more common between the two ( see NGram below) :

> - Generally, only the largest of rivers, which are often estuaries, are said to have shores.
> - Rivers and other flowing bodies of water are said to have banks.
>     ( [Wiktionary)](http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/shore)

[Shore](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Shore):

> - (Physical Geography) the land along the edge of a sea, lake, or wide river.

[Bank](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bank):

> - The slope of land adjoining a body of water, especially adjoining a river, lake, or channel.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=river%20shore%2Criver%20bank%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Criver%20shore%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Criver%20bank%3B%2Cc0) : *river bank vs river shore*

(TFD)

Answer (score 1):

This may be a regional thing, but in Pittsburgh we have a lot of rivers and it is common to refer to the "shore".  In fact, the ["North Shore"](http://www.visitpittsburgh.com/about-pittsburgh/neighborhoods/north-shore-and-north-side/) and ["South Shore"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Shore_(Pittsburgh)) are prominent areas/neighborhoods.  You can also see the use in things like this Three Rivers Trail [description](http://www.traillink.com/trail/three-rivers-heritage-trail.aspx):

> The Hazelwood segment instead turns to the Monongahela River, running south along its **eastern shore** to Pittsburgh’s Hazelwood neighborhood.

Usages like these would not have shown up in Josh61's NGram for "river shore" because the word "river" is implied.

Comment: Excellent point re Ngrams and the search phrase.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of a "rivershore" and it sure sounds awkward to me, so I checked with my trusty American Heritage dictionary 3rd ed. and I find these: riverbank, riverfront, and riverside. Of these, "riverbank" may be most commonly used here -although usually it is not actually referring to the size or slope of the land abutting the river.